# Envio de objetos complexos via HttpGet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Tenho um método de busca em minha WebApi, como é uma busca, utilizei `[HttpGet]`, como parâmetro desse método, passo um objeto com as opções de filtro que desejo, por exemplo:

```
public class ParametrosBusca {
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime dataInicial { get; set; }
    public DateTime dataFinal { get; set; }
}
```

A declaração do método:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Buscar(ParametrosBusca parametros) {
   //...//
}
```

Ao chamar minha Api passando o parâmetro, meu objeto não é deserializado, porém, seu eu alterar o método para receber o parâmetro do tipo string eu o recebo corretamente e consigo deserializar corretamente, dessa maneira:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Buscar (string parametros) {
    var teste = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ParametrosBusca>(parametros);
    //...//
}
```

Caso eu use `[HttpPost]`, meu parâmetro também e deserializado corretamente.

Minha pergunta, não posso passar objetos complexos em métodos do tipo `HttpGet`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [vinculação de parâmetro](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) do Web API funciona da seguinte forma:

- Se o parâmetro for um tipo simples, o Web API tenta obter o
  valor da URI. Os tipos simples incluem os tipos primitivos do .NET
  (`int`, `bool`, `double` e assim por diante), além de `TimeSpan`, `DateTime`,
  `Guid`, `decimal` e `string`, além de qualquer tipo com um conversor de
  tipos que possa ser convertido de uma string.
- Para tipos complexos, o Web API tenta ler o valor do **corpo da
  requisição** (*request body*).

O problema é que o método `GET` não pode ter um *body* e todos os valores são codificados na URI. Portanto, é necessário forçar o Web API a ler um tipo complexo da URI.

Para fazer isso, você pode adicionar o atributo `[FromUri]` ao parâmetro:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Buscar([FromUri] ParametrosBusca parametros)
```

Comment: Show.. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @mercador tem alguma vantagem em usar [FromUri] no get em vez de fazer um post?

Comment: @Aesir eu não diria que há vantagem ou desvantagem, e sim que é importante manter a consistência do objetivo das requisições. `GET` é recomendado para receber dados do servidor, enquanto que `POST` é usado para enviar informações com o intuito de torná-las persistentes.